# How to enable CORS in AWS API Gateway for an Android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, security, cors, aws-api-gateway

How to enable CORS in AWS API Gateway such that only my app can connect to the API?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for authentication, CORS might not be right choice here. Moreover if the javascript is not running on a domain (Like a website), you wan't be able to restrict domain.

For authentication you should try IAM Auth provided in API-Gateway. All you have to do it SigV4 sign each request.

Answer (score 0):

Add your domain name instead of '*' as follows:

```
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'www.example.com'
```

Comment: how to do that in android  app